# How do I set the printInfo to print in landscape in OS X?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I have set the following code:

```
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo
let textPrint = NSPrintOperation(view: theTextView,printInfo: printInfo())
```

Now I would like to set the *orientation* to *Landscape*, but I can't find any Swift functions that do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm using.  The NSView is called drawing.

```
let pinfo = NSPrintInfo.shared()
pinfo.orientation = .landscape
pinfo.bottomMargin = 0.0
pinfo.topMargin = 0.0
pinfo.leftMargin = 0.0
pinfo.rightMargin = 0.0
drawing!.print(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let pmPageFormat = printInfo.PMPageFormat()
PMSetOrientation(pmPageFormat, kPMLandscape, kPMUnlocked)
printInfo.updateFromPMPageFormat()
```

Comment: I tried this but get the following compile errors: () -> NSPrintInfo' does not have a member named 'PMPageFormat' , also '() -> NSPrintInfo' does not have a member named 'updateFromPMPageFormat'

Comment: The first line of your code is missing parentheses. It should be `let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()`. You were getting a reference to the function rather than calling the function and getting its result. Of course, you then should **not** have parenthesis when passing the `printInfo` on your next line. Pass `printInfo`, not `printInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss the parentheses, However, I still get the Cannot invoke 'PMSetOrientation' with an argument list of type '(() UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, Int, Int)' in the PMSetOrientation(pmPageFormat, kPMLandscape, kPMUnlocked) statement

Comment: Did you include the parentheses in the first line of my code when you copied it?

Comment: Yes. Here is all the code:       let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()
        let textPrint = NSPrintOperation(view: theTextView,printInfo: printInfo)
        let pmPageFormat = printInfo.PMPageFormat
        PMSetOrientation(PMCreatePageFormat(pmPageFormat, kPMLandscape, kPMUnlocked)

Comment: Right, you've forgotten the parentheses at the end of `let pmPageFormat = printInfo.PMPageFormat()`. Also, you should set the orientation before creating the `NSPrintOperation`, just to be sure.

Comment: I already tried that with the same compile error. This may be an apple problem.